# Gitlab Runner not pulling image defined as service in gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

For some reason, the Gitlab Runner in Gitlab is not pulling or using an image I've defined as a service in my gitlab-ci.yml. I installed gitlab-runner locally, and everything works fine, but when I push to Gitlab, it doesn't work. I'm losing it over here.

gitlab-ci.yml:

```
build:
  stage: build
  services:
    - mysql
  image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable
```

Output from Gitlab, only using the `image`, not the image defined by `services`:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
  on gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-3695154600-vj3bh (8620b628)
Using Kubernetes namespace: default
Using Kubernetes executor with image chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable ...
Waiting for pod default/runner-8620b628-project-1-concurrent-0jqbbv to be running, status is Pending
Running on runner-8620b628-project-1-concurrent-0jqbbv via gitlab-runner-gitlab-runner-3695154600-vj3bh...
Cloning repository...
```

Output from my local machine, pulling both:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.0 (413da38)
  on  ()
Using Docker executor with image chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable ...
Starting service mysql:latest ...
Pulling docker image mysql:latest ...
Using docker image mysql:latest ID=sha256:f0f3956a9dd825e3195f0d1a4fe17cc94b0f6934fc470b09abf8fad87d17ff24 for mysql service...
Waiting for services to be up and running...
Using docker image sha256:64cbb31659359752dd4fb4580047faf5b0ec487258d09ca8a97897a0ba615d1b for predefined container...
Pulling docker image chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable ...
Using docker image chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable ID=sha256:a07a953be1b12bc294b5bbdb229fe7312c2916b7ad3397ff970b8145165e36e7 for build container...
Running on runner--project-0-concurrent-0 via mchale...
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out. Was due to the nature of the Kubernetes executor, which works a little differently. When building using Kubernetes, services are build in the pod alongside the runner container, and so the runner does not announce that it's loading that image. More info here:

[More info](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/2417)

Answer (score 1):

You have to define `services` on the root level of your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. As seen in the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#define-image-and-services-from-gitlab-ci-yml).

Your file would look like this:

```
services:
  - mysql:latest

variables:
  # Configure mysql environment variables (https://hub.docker.com/r/_/mysql/)
  MYSQL_DATABASE: el_duderino
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql_strong_password

build:
  stage: build
  image: chilio/laravel-dusk-ci:stable
```

Comment: It works both ways. As seen in the link you sent: "It is also possible to define different images and services per job:"

Comment: And by "works", I mean "It should work both ways." In my case, neither method fixes my issue.